# add a table below a text in a file, Matlab fprinf fopen

Tags: matlab, text, printf, fopen

I'm using Matlab to develop weather data.
I need to add few lines above the data.

I have a matrix with different data in columns. Let's say:

```
t=[2;3;6;8;9];      % temperature
v=[10;11;12;10;11]; % wind speed
r=[500;650;750;1000;750]; % solar radiation

table=array2table([t,v,r]);
writetable(table,'file.txt','WriteVariableNames',0);

location='rome';
year=2015;

line1=[location,'_',num2str(year)];
```

Now I need to add `line1` above the numbers.
How can I use `fopen` and `fprintf`? With `fprintf` I just can indicate `'w'` and `'a'`, that is to say overwrite or add below the text.

I thought I could do the contrary: first create a text file with `line1` and than use the option `'a'` to append the table below.

Unfortunately I can't do it: could you make me an example with my variables?

Thank you

Comment: What did you actually try and what didn't work about it?

Comment: If I type this:
`fid=fopen('file.txt');
fmt='%s';
fprintf(fid,fmt,line1);
fclose(fid);`

I obtain nothing, the file is the same as before

Comment: The default permission is `'r'`, so how about trying it with `'a'` like you asked?

Comment: uh ok it works. Now I'm trying to do the contrary, as explained:
`t=[2;3;6;8;9];      % temperature
v=[10;11;12;10;11]; % wind speed
r=[500;650;750;1000;750]; % solar radiation
table=array2table([t,v,r]);

location='rome';
year=2015;
line1={location,'_',num2str(year)};
lineT=cell2table(line1);

writetable(lineT,'file.txt','WriteVariableNames',0);

fid=fopen('file.txt','a');
fmt='%t';
fprintf(fid,fmt,table);
fclose(fid);`

Again, nothing happens. I get 'rome,_,2015'